# Create a slash effect using image and progressively drawing

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, sprite

### What I want

To create an effect like an *slash* in my 2D project. For that, I've an image in my assets already, and I want to draw it from top to the bottom, allowing it to be drawn in maybe half a second, progressively.

The idea is to draw it to create the effect of the slash itself, and the progressively mode is to "fit" the slash image itself, imagine the first one of the following [link](https://browse.startpage.com/do/show_picture.pl?l=espanol&rais=1&oiu=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.freepik.com%2Fvector-gratis%2Fvarios-sprites-juego-slash_7814-463.jpg&sp=d879121c738451070bbe46673a44c4e4&t=default), that would be drawn from left to right.

To achieve that kind of drawing, the only thing that I've found is [fillAmount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html) for an Image, combined with the [fillMethod](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.FillMethod.html).

### The problem

The problem is that these methods are for the `Image` class, that it's not recommended for game drawing but only for UI.

Anyway, I've tried to do it this way, and I've not been able to do it, because the Unity environment didn't let me drag&drop my slash asset into the `Image` variable that I had created into my script. I thought that it may be because of the type of import, but also trying to import it with the other options resulted in nothing better.

### The questions

Just answering one of these questions would solve my situation (or I think so):

1. How can I make Unity accept my image/asset into my `Image` object in the script?
2. Another way to create such effect using `Sprite` or `GameObjects` directly?

Comment: Can sprite animation meet your demand?

Comment: I suppose it can, although I don't know exactly how to do it. @siusiulala

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: You can use sprite sheet to create a 2D animation**

1-1. Prepare a splash effect sprite sheet (an image map contains continuous action image), like [image]

1-2. Change the sprite mode to multiple in inspector window
[image]

1-3. Slice the sprites in sprite editor
[image]

1-4. Multi-select the sprites and drag into hierarchy window, Unity will ask you to save this animation
[image]
[image]

1-5. You will get an animation GameObject

[image]

**Method 2: If you can make it like a circular progress bar, check [Radial/ Circular Progress Bar in unity3d](http://gyanendushekhar.com/2017/03/28/radial-circular-progress-bar-unity3d/)**